# Does RAM taken up Shared Memory connection counts against Max Server Memory?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

I have an app that's local to the SQL Server and thus has a Shared Memory connection to it.  I was wondering whether the RAM taken by the connection (including data transfers) counts against the max memory limit set for the SQL Server.

The reason I am asking is that the SQL Server is maxed out on memory (e.g. Target Server Memory = Total Server Memory and other metrics).  If the RAM taken up by Shared Memory connection counts against it, wouldn't I be better off using TCP connection to the SQL Server?

Comment: Network buffers consume memory as well!

Answer (score 3):

The "max server memory" option only applies to the buffer pool, not to memory reserved for connections.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only from SQL2012 onwards, if I remember correctly from Bob Ward's 2013 PASS session (gave me a headache!)

Comment: there's a KB [Memory configuration and sizing considerations in SQL Server 2012](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2663912)